# Improve performance of forEach iteraction

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, foreach

I am attempting to filter a larger array (10K) records against a smaller (2K) array.

Using this code takes almost 5 seconds to complete.

```
let inventory = []
allItems.forEach((item) => {
  localOrders.forEach((order) => {
    if (item.id === Number(order.itemId)) {
      inventory.push({
        item,
        order,
        type: 'local',
      })
    }
  })
  onlineOrders.forEach((order) => {
    if (item.id === Number(order.itemId)) {
      inventory.push({
        item,
        order,
        type: 'online',
      })
    }
  })
})

return inventory
```

The reason I use forEach rather than filter (which is much faster at 90 ms) is I am looking for two different items in the same (10K) array.  Even if I used filter, I would still need to attach the data from primary and secondary array to a final object that includes all the data for them.

What is my best option to optimize this so it isn't so slow, but satisfies my requirement of  a final array that includes item details and order details?

Comment: Assuming `id` is unique you could surely add a `break`.

Comment: You should convert your `localOrders` and `onlineOrders` into `Map`s or `object`s using the ids as keys, so that looksup become O(1) on average. this will make your code only execute `k*10000` operations instead of `k*5000*10000`.

Comment: See for example, this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984612/create-a-map-of-objects-from-an-array-via-lodash

Comment: use  `break` if `id` is unique, Or you should use `Map` instead of array, If `allItems` or `localOrders, onlineOrders`  is sorted, then use binary search,

Comment: @JavaScript I converted it to a for of loop since foreach doesn't support break and went from 4300ms to about 4100ms.  It is an improvement, but still really slow.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your three lists have this structure :

```
const allItems = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 9 }];
const localOrders = [{ itemId: 3 }, { itemId: 7 }];
const onlineOrders = [{ itemId: 5 }, { itemId: 7 }];
```

First idea: it is much cheaper to go through `localOrders` and `onlineOrders` than through `allItems`, which can be a MUCH larger list. Besides, in your current code, you are iterating EACH object in the longest list, and for each one of these objects, you are iterating the entirety of `localOrders` and `onlineOrders`. So it's a good idea to do the opposite and start with the shorter lists.

For each local order, you want to find the corresponding item in the big list with `allItems.find(item => item.id===localOrder.itemId)`. Unlike `.forEach()`, `.find()` stops traversing the array as soon as it finds the element, which saves you a lot of cycles.

So you can start with something like this :

```
let inventory = localOrders.map(localOrder => ({
  item : allItems.find(item => item.id===localOrder.itemId),
  order : localOrder,
  type: 'local',
}))
```

That's for the local orders, now the online orders :

```
inventory = inventory.concat(onlineOrders.map(onlineOrder => ({
  item : allItems.find(item => item.id===onlineOrder.itemId),
  order : onlineOrder,
  type: 'online',
})))
```

It works, but it's a little clumsy though, because you are repeating pretty much the same code twice. And if you have a third type of order, you will repeat the same code three times, four times, etc. So, a more clever way of doing things is to put the orders in an object, so you can have as many types of orders as you want without repeating yourself, something like this :

```js
const allItems = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 9 }];

const orders = {
  "local" : [{ itemId: 3 }, { itemId: 7 }],
  "online" : [{ itemId: 5 }, { itemId: 7 }],
  "delayed" : [{ itemId: 8 }]
}

let inventory = [];

Object.keys(orders).forEach( type => { // type=="local", type=="online"
  inventory = inventory.concat(orders[type].map(localOrder => ({
    item : allItems.find(item => item.id===localOrder.itemId),
    order : localOrder,
    type,
  })))
})

console.log(inventory);
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is almost twice the time to complete.

Comment: I have made a benchmark in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/PoJYLrr?editors=0010). With 10k elements in `allItems`, your method takes 6.54ms, mine takes 2.07ms (3 times faster). With 100k items, yours 16ms, mine 6ms (2.5 times faster). With 1 million item, yours 71ms, mine 5ms (14 times faster). With 10 million items, yours 650ms, mine 5.8ms (112 times faster). Check for yourself. My method just _cannot_ be slower than yours, simply because your method always iterates EVERY item of EVERY array, it is the longest and the slowest possible. What's your benchmark? Can I check it?

Comment: I am using javascript time before and after to calculate, but I am also sure it takes 5+ seconds as it is slow.  I will try to do a codepen, the data that populates allItems is like 6MB.